# What is [super awakeFromNib]; used for?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I often see this line of code

```
[super awakeFromNib]
```

in the `awakeFromNib` method in the implementation of a view controller

My understanding is it is telling the super class of this view controller (which would be the window) to `awakeFromNib`.
Am I right? If so, why do we have to tell the window to awake in the `awakeFromNib` method of a UIView Controller sub-class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> My understanding is it is telling the super class of this view controller ...

right so far...

> (which would be the window)

oops - that's the source of your confusion.

The "super class of the view controller" is `UIViewController`. "super" is referring to the base class that your UIViewController sub-class inherits from; it doesn't have anything to do with the window that encloses your view.

So, what this is doing is invoking the default `awakeFromNib` implementation of a basic `UIViewController`, in addition to whatever you're doing in your sub-class implementation.

Comment: Thanks. Ok, then why do we have to tell UIViewController to awake?

Comment: It may have state information that it wants to initialize after being loaded from a nib file. In general, it's good practice to call the `super` implementation of any methods you override in your sub-class.

Answer (score 1):

What David said above is correct,

Now for your question "why do we have to tell the window to awake in the awakeFromNib method of a UIView Controller sub-class?"

if there is any custom modification or any data that you want to load before your ViewController loads we should use the `awakeFromNib`.

`awakeFromNib` is called when the controller itself is unarchived from a nib.